# Front derailleur compatibility of Shimano 3x10 speed flat bar shifters

Tags: shimano, shifter, compatibility

I'm trying to find a pair of 3x10 speed flat bar shifters and am somewhat confused over the compatibility.

My understanding was that all (front) road shifters up to 10 speed can be [mixed and matched](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/60044) with any (front) derailleur (except for Tiagra 4700).

I found [this](http://www.bicirace.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2016-2017_Compatibility_v030_en.pdf) Shimano compatibility chart, from which I had assumed SL-R783 is compatible with the old triple front derailleurs.

When measuring, both SL-R783 and SL-4703 pull the same amount of cable (1-3: ~13,5 mm). Older triple shifters (from a 7 speed group) pull ~21,0 mm of cable between first and third positions.

Therefore, I would think that the (front, left) SL-R783 shifter is not compatible with for instance an Deore XT FD-M771.

Do there exist any 3x10 speed flat bar (road) shifters compatible with old style (Shimano 7/8/9 speed MTB or road) front and rear derailleurs? I'm specifically looking for flat bar shifters (with trimming function) compatible with (9 speed) Deore XT FD-M771 and RD-M771.

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you mean by 'old style' derailleurs? What specific derailleurs do you have?

Comment: Regarding mixing and matching road shifters/derailleurs up to 10 speed, the *rear* derailleur actuation ratios are well known and [documented](https://www.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/), but I've never seen something similar for front derailleurs.

Comment: @tdr you appear to have created two separate accounts, which is why your edit to your own question required review.   Please use the original account and I'll delete the other

Comment: Read this for reference https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1297/bicycle-front-derailleur-compatibility/